# Prevent parallel releases in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have an API Management System and we created Python Scripts to push new API's to the platform, we have 5 environments defined in TFS - DEV, SYS, ACC, REL and PROD.

We have one release create for each API.

If two releases running at the same time for the same environment we get some issues sometimes and I would like to configure so that two or more releases will have be serialized - i.e queued and executed after each other.

The only solution I found so far is to only allow use of one agent but that would be slow as we a large enterprise and agents are busy and they can change without notice.

Currently on version 16.131.28601.4 of Team Foundation Server but we can move over to a new version of Azure Devops.

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answers are helpful for you? If yes, you can accept one as the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 0):

Each release will start from stage 1. Thus we can add a PowerShell task as the first task for stage 1 to check if there are previous in-progress deployments.

In this PowerShell task, we can call this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) to check release stage status.

Power shell script:

```
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
    $token = "$(pat)"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $success = $false
    $count = 0
do{
    try{
    $stageurl2 = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId={release definition ID}&deploymentStatus=inProgress&api-version=4.1-preview.2"
    $stageinfo2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $stageurl2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
   
    $inprogressdeployments = $stageinfo2.value | where {($_.deploymentStatus -eq "inProgress")  -and ($_.release.name -ne $ENV:RELEASE_RELEASENAME)  -and ($_.releaseEnvironment.name -ne 'stop services')} | Sort-Object -Property completedOn -Descending
    #write-output $inprogressdeployments
    $stageurl3 = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId={release definition ID}&operationStatus=QueuedForAgent&api-version=4.1-preview.2"
    $stageinfo3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $stageurl3 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    $queueddeployments = $stageinfo3.value
    #write-output $queueddeployments
        if($inprogressdeployments) {            
            Write-output "Deployment In Progress, Waiting for it to finish!"  
            Write-output "Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30          
      } else {            
            Write-Host "No Current Deployment in Progress"
            if($queueddeployments) {
            write-output "Current Queued deployments"
            Write-output "if 2 - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30 
            }
            else{
            write-output "No Queued deployments, starting release"
            $success = $true      
            }      
      }
    }
    catch{
        Write-output "catch - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
        write-output "1"
        Start-sleep -Seconds 30
      # Put the start-sleep in the catch statemtnt so we
      # don't sleep if the condition is true and waste time
    }
    
    $count++
    
}until($count -eq 2000 -or $success)
if(-not($success)){exit}
```

Result: Stage1 will continue to check until all previous versions are completed

[image]

This workaround is provided by this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992103/prevent-parallel-execution-of-same-release-pipeline-in-azure-devops), you can refer to it for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invoke REST API gate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#configure-a-gate) to call below [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) rest api and check if there are any releases in deployment. See below steps:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress&api-version=5.0
```

1, Add a Invoke Rest Api Gate

Go to Pre-deployment conditions --> Enable Gate-->Add a Invoke Rest Api Gate-->Click Manage to create a service connection.

2, Create a service connection.

When you Click Manage in above step. You will be forward to service connections page. Click new service connection and select Generic type of service connection:

- **The server Url**: `https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}`
- **Password**: `Personal Access Token`

3, Go back to the Invoke Rest Api Gate. Select the service connection just created: See below

- **Method**: Get
- **URL** suffix and parameters: `/_apis/release/deployments?operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress&api-version=5.0`
- **Success criteria**: `eq(root['value'][0], '')`

Above Invoke rest api gate will call the deployments list rest api to filter these releases that are inProgress or queued of deployment using operationStatus filter(ie. operationStatus=queued,queuedForAgent,phaseInProgress). If the there is any deloyment is inProgress or queued the Success criteria: eq(root['value'][0], '') will failed. And the release will wait until there is not active deployment.

If you move over to a new version of Azure Devops. You can check out the [Exclusive lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#exclusive-lock)

> The exclusive lock check allows only a single run from the pipeline to proceed. All stages in all runs of that pipeline which use the resource are paused

Answer (score 0):

In each environment you can configure that only 1 release can be deployed at the same time:

[image]

> Deployment on an environment can be in parallel wherein multiple
> releases can be deployed at the same time or in order where releases
> get deployed one after another. Specify '1' for deployments to go one
> after another (sequential).

Comment: This only prevent paralell execution of one specific release - But I want to block paralell execution for all releases defined under a project.